# Unable to locate element in Selenium no such element javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate sign up on website.
Here is the button I want to click:
Sign up

I get the error: 
"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="email"]"}"
I don't have any idea why it doesnt find this element. I put a long sleep, I can see this element, but Selenium does not.

Whole page:

````
var By = webdriver.By;
var driver;

class signUpPage {
    constructor() {
        driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
    }

    typeCorrectEmail() {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="email"]'));
    }

    clickSignUpButton() {
      driver.findElement(By.id("signup")).click();
    }

}
module.exports = new signUpPage();```

tests.js file:

```var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

var homePage = require('./homePage');
var signUpPage = require('./signUpPage');

homePage.navigateToTrello();
driver.sleep(5000);

homePage.clickSignInButton();
driver.sleep(10000);

signUpPage.typeCorrectEmail();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Type  `$x('//*[@id="email"]')`, into the developer console to validate and see if the locator exists - does it show up?

The first step is to see if this is a valid locator, if so then there is a problem with the code you have written. If it doesn't show up, you need to find another way to identify the element.

More information here: https://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/